# Laravel Scheduled job

Tags: laravel, cron, forever

I'm running CRON JOB with Laravel.

I scheduled it as given below.
$schedule->command('remind:planner_notif')->cron('* * * * *')->withoutOverlapping();

But I wanted to run it forever like while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$schedule->command('remind:planner_notif')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```

or for example **daily**:

```
$schedule->command('remind:planner_notif')->daily()->withoutOverlapping()
```

and make sure in your hositng run the this:

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that in the command that is being executed. The scheduler's job is to run the command and nothing more. So add the conditions needed in the code for the command `remind:planner_notif`